# Magento 2 commands automatically killed

Tags: magento2.3, command-line, setup-di-compile, ssh

I am running commands setup:di:compile and cache: clean it's running for while, but after sometime it got killed in magento2.3.2. Please let me know the exact issue for this.

Comment: you try this command **`php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile`**

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Can you check memory limit of php?